# Allow test to complete if specified duration has been reached

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am trying to use the step-load-pattern with one of my webtests. The duration is set to 10 mins for 50 users.

In VS (visual studio 2013), when the 10 mins is reached, it ends the load test causing any running test test user instances to abort. Is there a setting that will tell VS that once duration is reached, allow completion of running virtual users and then end the load test?

Thank you for the help,

Sainath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "run settings" section of the load test has a "cool down duration" property. Its purpose is for exactly the situation you describe. Any tests still executing at the end of the cool down will just be terminated. Tests that run during the "cool down period" (also those that start during the "warm up duration", another "run settings" property) will not contribute to the test results. At least, that is stated somewhere in the documentation, but in practice I think warm-up and cool-down tests do contribute to some of the results statistics.

See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406976.aspx) for more details.